# Blazor Component

Tags: blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly, blazor-component

Please find my Blazor component here, I need to loop through the list one time only.

How can I prevent to go through the loop after changing the text value to save time?

When I debug it, I find each time I change text value it loops again
this affects on page performance badly.

```html
<input type="text" value="@num" />
<button type="button" @onclick="UpdateValue">Update TextBox </button> 
<br />
@foreach(int x in lst)
{
 @x
 <br />
}
```

```cs
@code { 
 int num;
 List<int> lst = new List<int>();
 protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
 {
  lst.Add(1);
  lst.Add(2);
  lst.Add(3);
  lst.Add(4);
 }
 private void UpdateValue() => this.num = 10;
 // Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync( //EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object arg) => callback.InvokeAsync(arg); 
}
```

I need to not loop again when I change text value

Comment: <input type="text" value="@num" />
<button type="button" @onclick="UpdateValue">Update TextBox </button>
<br />
@foreach(int x in lst)
{ @x<br />}
@code {
    int num;
    List<int> lst = new List<int>();
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        lst.Add(1);
        lst.Add(2);
        lst.Add(3);
        lst.Add(4);
    }
    private void UpdateValue() => this.num = 10;
    //    Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(
    //EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object arg) => callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
}

Comment: <input type="text" value="@num" />
<button type="button" @onclick="UpdateValue">Update TextBox </button>
<br />
@foreach(int x in lst)
{ @x<br />}
@code {
    int num;
    List<int> lst = new List<int>();
    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        lst.Add(1);
        lst.Add(2);
        lst.Add(3);
        lst.Add(4);

    }
    private void UpdateValue() => this.num = 10;
    //    Task IHandleEvent.HandleEventAsync(
    //EventCallbackWorkItem callback, object arg) => callback.InvokeAsync(arg);
}
```

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.